# Como otimizar esse código?

Tags: python-3.x, algoritmo

Um loop musical é um trecho de música que foi composto para repetir continuamente (ou seja, o trecho inicia novamente toda vez que chega ao final). Loops podem ser digitalizados por exemplo utilizando PCM. PCM, do inglês Pulse Code Modulation, é uma técnica para representação de sinais analógicos, muito utilizada em áudio digital. Nessa técnica, a magnitude do sinal é amostrada a intervalos regulares de tempo, e os valores amostrados são armazenados em sequência. Um pico em uma forma de onda é um valor de uma amostra que representa um máximo ou mínimo local, ou seja, um ponto de inflexão da forma de onda.

### ENTRADA

A entrada contém vários casos de teste. A primeira linha de um caso de teste contém um inteiro N, representando o número de amostras no loop musical. A segunda linha contém N inteiros, separados por espaços, representando a sequência de magnitudes das amostras.
O final da entrada é indicado por uma linha que contém apenas o número zero.

### SAÍDA

Para cada caso de teste da entrada seu programa deve imprimir uma única linha, contendo apenas um inteiro, o número de picos existentes no loop musical.

[link](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1089) para esse problema no URI

Para resolver esse problema fiz esse programa, que funciona, mas é muito lento:

```
while True:
    n = int(input())

    if n == 0:
        break

    loop = list(map(int, input().split()))  """ criando lista a partir dos inputs """
    listaSentido = []  """ lista para armazenar o sentido da onda, +1 para crescente -1 para decrescente """

    for i in range(len(loop)): """ por se tratar de um loop, o ultimo elemento da lista se relaciona ao primeiro
                                   assim, verifico se o elemento que estou analisando é o último """
        if i + 1 < len(loop):

            if loop[i] > loop[i + 1]: """ Sendo o valor seguinte menor, temos sentido decrescente, e adicionamos -1 """
                cente = -1            """ à lista auxiliar, caso contrário, adicionamos +1 """
                listaSentido.append(cente)
            else:
                cente = 1
                listaSentido.append(cente)
        else:                                 """ quando chego ao último elemento da lista, o comparo com o primeiro """
            if loop[(len(loop)-1)] > loop[0]:
                listaSentido.append(-1)
            else:
                listaSentido.append(1)

        inversao = 0                          """ estabeleço um contador para monitorar a quantidade de vezes que o sentido mudou """
        for i in range(len(listaSentido)):    """ pois quando o sentido muda, certamente há um pondo de inflexão """
            if i + 1 < len(listaSentido):
                if listaSentido[i] != listaSentido[i + 1]:  """ sempre cuidando para que o último elemento seja comparado com o primeiro """
                    inversao += 1
            else:
                if listaSentido[len(listaSentido)-1] != listaSentido[0]:
                    inversao += 1
    
    print(inversao) """ no fim, o valor armazenado em inversão é correspondente ao número de picos (máximos e mínimos) """
```

Reparem que eu analiso a lista `loop`, baseado nela eu crio uma segunda lista `listaSentido` que armazena o sentido da onda e só então calculo os picos. Acredito que não seja necessária a criação dessa segunda lista. Criar e depois analisá-la consome muito tempo. Mas como calcular esse valor apenas pela lista `loop`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **1089** da categorial **AD-HOC** do site **URI**.

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1089) a íntegra do enunciado.

Pois bem, para resolvermos esta questão basta utilizarmos o seguinte código:

```
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    h = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    h.append(h[0])
    h.append(h[1])
    picos = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if h[i] < h[i - 1] and h[i] < h[i + 1]:
            picos += 1
        elif h[i] > h[i - 1] and h[i] > h[i + 1]:
            picos += 1
    print(picos)
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos uma tela **preta** com o cursor piscando no canto `superior esquerdo`. Neste momento devemos digitar um `número inteiro` e pressionar `enter`. Neste momento o **1º bloco if** verificará o valor de `n`. Caso o valor seja **igual a 0**, será encerrada a execução do código. Caso contrário, receberemos novamente o cursor **piscando** abaixo do valor de `n`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os possíveis valores de `h`, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e, no final, pressionar `enter`. Tendo realizado estas operações o bloco for irá percorrer o **range(1, n + 1)** realizando as verificações pertinentes. Neste momento o bloco **if** verificará se `h[i]` é **menor** que seu antecessor `(h[i - 1])` e, também, se é **menor** que o seu sucessor `(h[i + 1])` e, caso positivo, acumulará o valor da unidade na variável `picos`. Caso a condição do `if` não seja satisfeita, o código é direcionado para o `elif`. Chegando no `elif` será verificado se o valor de `h[i]` é **maior** que seu antecessor `(h[i - 1])` e, também, se é **maior** que seu sucessor `(h[i + 1])` e, caso positivo, acumulará o valor da unidade na variável `picos`. E, finalizando, exibirá o resultado.

**Observação:**

Este código já foi **testado**, **submetido** e devidamente **aprovado** no site URI. E, só para constar, este código levou apenas **0.017 s** para ser executado no referido site.

Comment: @yoyo, solução da questão `1089` do `URI`. Tempo de execução apenas `0.017 s`. Minha posição do URI 12º (Carlos Silva).

Answer (score -1):

Não sei muito bem a lógica por trás disso, mas segue minha revisão. Acredito que esteja mais eficiente, quando possível dê uma conferida, por favor:

```
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    loop = list(map(int, input().split()))
    i = i0 = loop.pop(0)
    cente = None
    inversao = 0
    for i2 in loop:
        ultimo_cente = cente
        cente = i2 > i
        if cente != ultimo_cente:
            inversao += 1
        i = i2
    if cente != (i < i0):
        inversao += 1
    print(inversao)
```